# Wordpress white screen when launching from AWS EC2 AMI

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I've created an AWS EC2 instance with a Wordpress site running on it. The MySQL database is on Amazon RDS and everything works perfectly. I've created an image from the EC2 instance and a snapshot from the RDS instance and attempted to bring up the site using the new instances but I keep getting a blank white screen. I can connect to the new RDS instance using MySQL Workbench so it looks like it's running. I can open up a phpinfo.php page on the EC2 instance so it looks like the web server is running. I've modified the wp-config.php file to point to the new RDS instance and changed the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE to point to the new EC2 instance. Still getting a blank screen. Any other options I can try? I've set WP_DEBUG to true but I don't get any error messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the apache `error_log`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience White Screens are commonly database issues.

Ensure you're connecting correctly and that the WordPress database is correct.

At a guess of the most likely problem; your `/wp-config.php` should contain the correct database hostname `instance-name.randomcode.amazon-region.rds.amazonaws.com` as opposed to `localhost`. This is because if you're running an RDS instance for your database it's a different server and than your AWS instance. This means it's not on the AWS `localhost`.

For more info the AWS docs are usually somewhat helpful. You can find them [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html)

Comment: Thanks Joshua. It actually turned out to be an issue with the IP address of the EC2 instance in the security group for the RDS instance. Once I got that squared away I was able to connect without an issue.